# SQL Query: How to get all employees with their information and all courses names with showing the courses that the employee has taken them

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables in my database:
**Employee Table** which consists of Name, Id , Organization
**Course Table** which consists of CourseName, CourseId

And each employee can take many courses, so we have many-to-many relationship. For that, I will create another table which is **employee_course** which consists of employee_id and course_id

My problem now is: 
How to get all the employees with their information and all courses names with showing the courses that the employee has taken them?

The result should give me the following: for example if employee A took course #1 and #2, in the SQL Server Management Studio, I should get:

employee A ................................ course#1

employee A ................................ course#2

My query:

```
SELECT     dbo.employee.Name, dbo.employee.BadgeNo, dbo.employee.Division, dbo.employee.Organization, dbo.courses.CourseName, 
                      dbo.employee_courses.courseId AS Expr1
FROM         dbo.courses LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.employee_courses ON dbo.courses.CourseID = dbo.employee_courses.courseId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.employee ON dbo.employee_courses.employeeId = dbo.employee.BadgeNo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a query in this form:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  employee
LEFT JOIN employee_courses ON (
  dbo.employee_courses.employeeId = dbo.employee.BadgeNo
)
INNER JOIN courses ON (
  dbo.courses.CourseID = dbo.employee_courses.courseId
)
```

I've put 'employee' first as this is the table that will definitely have columns, and it left-joins to the other two.

Edit: fixed joins.

Comment: I tried it but I got the following error:
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "dbo.courses.CourseID" could not be bound.

Comment: Oops, I had the joins the wrong way around - try that? Also, I don't know whether the schema "dbo" is necessary, as per CJM's answer. If it doesn't work still, try taking that out - IMO it's only necessary for multi-schema queries.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT e.EmployeeName, c.CourseName
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN employee_courses ec on ec.EmployeeID = e.BadgeNo
LEFT JOIN courses c on c.courseId = ec.courseId
```

I *think* I've got the column names right, but I'd check them first - the principle stands regardless.

If you want more specific responses, I'd suggest you post some DDL representing the key elements of your database, along with a few INSERTs of representative test data.